# Why my JavaScript about checkbox checked event is not workting

Tags: javascript, html, checkbox

I have 3 checkboxes, I want it like user can not choose more than 2 boxes. But my code has something wrong, I can't get any checkbox checked event work.

```js
function count() {
  var NewCount = 0;
  var s1 = document.getElementsById("s1");
  var s2 = document.getElementsById("s2");
  var s3 = document.getElementsById("s3");
  
  if (s1.checked) {    
    NewCount = NewCount + 1
    alert("for testing s1 checked");
  }

  if (s2.checked) {
    NewCount = NewCount + 1
    alert("for testing s2 checked");
  }

  if (s3.checked) {
    NewCount = NewCount + 1
    alert("for testing s3 checked");
  }

  if (NewCount == 3) {
    alert('Pick Just Two Please');
    return false;
  }
}
```

```html
<input type="checkbox" id="s1" name="service"  onchange="return count()">Service 1
<input type="checkbox" id="s2" name="service"  onchange="return count()">Service 2
<input type="checkbox" id="s3" name="service"  onchange="return count()">Service 3
```

This is the code which i uploaded to [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Y9f66/402/)

Comment: spelling error, getElementsById should be getElementById

Comment: Change `getElementsById` to `getElementById`

Comment: much appreciated!! didnt notice that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem was a typo. `getElementsById` to `getElementById` solved the problem

```js
function count() {
  var NewCount = 0;
  // getElementsById to getElementById
  var s1 = document.getElementById("s1");
  var s2 = document.getElementById("s2");
  var s3 = document.getElementById("s3");
  
  if (s1.checked) {    
    NewCount = NewCount + 1
    console.log("for testing s1 checked");
  }

  if (s2.checked) {
    NewCount = NewCount + 1
    console.log("for testing s2 checked");
  }

  if (s3.checked) {
    NewCount = NewCount + 1
    console.log("for testing s3 checked");
  }

  if (NewCount == 3) {
    alert('Pick Just Two Please');
    return false;
  }
  console.log("function done");
}
```

```html
<input type="checkbox" id="s1" name="service"  onchange="return count()">Service 1
<input type="checkbox" id="s2" name="service"  onchange="return count()">Service 2
<input type="checkbox" id="s3" name="service"  onchange="return count()">Service 3
```

Answer (score 0):

When in Fiddle, in addition to correcting the typo from getElementsById to getElementById, in the javascript window, please remember to set LOAD TYPE to "No wrap - in " as illustrated below:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

```js
function count(){
var NewCount = 0;
if (s1.checked) {    
    NewCount++;
    console.log("for testing s1 checked");
  }

  if (s2.checked) {
    NewCount++;
   console.log("for testing s2 checked");
  }

  if (s3.checked) {
    NewCount++;
    console.log("for testing s3 checked");
  }

  if (NewCount == 3) {
    alert('Pick Just Two Please');
    return false;
}
}
```

```html
<input type="checkbox" id="s1" name="service"  onchange="return count()">Service 1
<input type="checkbox" id="s2" name="service"  onchange="return count()">Service 2
<input type="checkbox" id="s3" name="service"  onchange="return count()">Service 3
```